# Deriving from a pure virtual template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pure-virtual

I'm getting a compilation error when I call the constructor of TestComp, which is designed as follows:

```
template <typename R> 
class IComparable
{
public:
    virtual bool Equals(const R & rhs) const = 0;
};

class TestComp : IComparable<char*>
{
public:
    std::string x;

    TestComp(std::string & a)
    {
        x = a;
    }

    virtual bool Equals(const char* & a) const
    {
        return x == std::string(a);
    }
};
```

Error:

```
error C2259: 'TestComp2' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:'bool IComparable<R>::Equals(const R &) const' : is abstract with [ R=char * ]
```

which I can't understand as I'm defining TestComp::Equals with what appears to be the same signature as IComparable::Equals.

One thing I've noticed when trying various workarounds is that if I make both functions 'Equals(R & rhs) const' removing the const from the parameter then I no longer get this error.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

The signature of the derived method is incorrect. It should be

```
virtual bool Equals(char* const& a) const
```

Note that the `const` is "applied" to the  type before the next closest `*` and `&` and `&&`, i.e.,

- `const char* &`, which is equivalent to `char const* &`, means a reference to a const-pointer to `char`.
- `char* const&` means a const-reference to a pointer to `char`.
- `const R&`, which is equivalent to `R const&`, means a const-reference to `R`.

Answer (score 2):

```
const R &
```

That is a `const` reference (or, pedantically, a reference to a `const` object).

```
const char* & a
```

That is a non-`const` reference (to a pointer to a `const` object); therefore, it doesn't override the function taking a `const` reference. You need a `const` reference to a non-`const` pointer:

```
char * const & a
```

The `const` always qualifies the thing *before* it, unless it comes at the start, in which case it qualifies the first thing. Some people suggest making a habit of consistently putting it after the thing it qualifies, i.e. `R const &` rather than `const R &`, to slightly reduce the opportunity for confusion.